# Disable Intellij @Nullable on "implement methods" when base method is androidx @Nullable

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, android-studio-4.2

In Android Studio 4.2 beta 1, whenever I implement a method annotated with the androidx version of @Nullable, the IDE is automatically adding the jetbrains @Nullable annotation as well.

This is extremely annoying as it results in code like:

```
  @Nullable
  @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable
  @Override
  public String foo(@Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable String bar) {
    return null;
  }
```

Any way to prevent this?

Comment: Please tell what version of androidx annotations do you use? What default annotations do you have defined in Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Configure annotations? Thanks

Comment: @OlgaKlisho AndroidX Annotations Version: 1.1.0.

Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler exists, but there is nothing mentioned about annotations below that.

Comment: Your issue seems to be the duplicate of https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-247941 and it should be fixed since IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2 Please see the workaround description https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-247941#focus=Comments-27-4363983.0-0

Comment: Thanks! oddly the `configure annotations` option is not in Android studio 4.2 beta 1.

I believe the next release of Android Studio migrates to IDEA 2020, so it'll probably be there then.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I ran into this problem and was able to fix it by going to Settings > Editor > Inspections > Probable Bugs > Nullability > @NotNull / @Nullable annotations. Then under Options, click the Configure Annotations button, select `androidx.annotation.Nullable` and `androidx.annotation.NonNull` from the respective lists, and press the checkmark to select them as the annotations.

Comment: Nice, this works. I think AS also fixed the default values at some point (currently using 2020.3.1-canary15)

Comment: Very annoying issue this fixed it, thanks

Answer (score 4):

As @jnmorris said, follow these steps :

Go to **Settings** > **Editor** > **Inspections** >

[image]

[image]

Find **Java** > **Probable Bugs** > **Nullability Problems** > **@NotNull/@Nullable Problems**

[image]

[image]

Click **Configure Annotations** button and check these items

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all the images, it made it alot easier to find them all.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehsn6.png)

Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> Probable Bugs -> Nullability -> @NotNull/Nullable Problem -> Configure Annotations -> click androidx.annotation.Nullable and androidx.annotation.NonNull

Comment: It's discouraged to post images.